# In Ruby on Rails, what's the difference between create and create! and API docs doesn't have it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

ActiveRecord has `create` and some people use `create!`...  Is it that `create!` can raise an exception while `create` doesn't?  I can't find `create!` in
the current Rails API docs...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `create!` will raise an exception on failure, `create` just returns false.  Documentation here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21

Comment: I was looking at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html and couldn't find it...  maybe there should be link to your page

Comment: @動靜能量: you can always check out the [RoR method index](http://api.rubyonrails.org/fr_method_index.html).  This is the lower left-hand frame when you go to api.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 3):

I have tested it in Rails `4.2.0`. In this version of Rails, it seems, `#create!` works as said in the other answer, but not the `#create` method.

[`#create`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create)

> creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The *resulting object is returned* whether the object was *saved successfully to the database or not*.

Here is some try as per the documentation.

```
Arup-iMac:rails_app_test shreyas$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
[1] pry(main)> show-models Person
Person
  id: integer
  name: string
  created_at: datetime
  updated_at: datetime
[2] pry(main)> Person.create!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
from /Users/shreyas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails_app_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
[3] pry(main)> Person.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Person:0x007fdb4cc5b0a0 id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[4] pry(main)> Person.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "people"
=> 0
[5] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  An exception is raised if the record is invalid.